# Conditional Validation using JQuery Validation Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, conditional-statements

I have a simple html form that I've added validation to using the JQuery Validation plugin. I have it working for single fields that require a value. I now need to extend that so that if a user answers Yes to a question they must enter something in the Details field, otherwise the Details field can be left blank. I'm using radio buttons to display the Yes/No. Here's my complete html form - I'm not sure where to go from here:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $.metadata.setType("attr", "validate");
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#editRecord").validate();
    });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css"> 
    .block { display: block; }
    form.cmxform label.error { display: none; } 
    </style>

    </head>
    <body>

            <div id="header">
                <h1>
                    Questions</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <h1>
                    Questions Page 1
                </h1>
          </div>
    <div id="content">
                <h1>
                </h1>
                <form class="cmxform" method="post" action="editrecord.php"     id="editRecord">
                <input type="hidden" name="-action" value="edit">
                  <h1>
                    Questions                
                  </h1>

          <table width="46%" class="record">
          <tr>
          <td width="21%" valign="top" class="field_name_left"><p>Question 1</p></td>
          <td width="15%" valign="top" class="field_data">
           <label for="Yes">
            <input type="radio" name="Question1" value="Yes" validate = "required:true" /> Yes
            </label>
            <label for="No">
   <input type="radio" name="Question1" value="No" /> No
            </label>
            <label for="Question1" class="error">You must answer this question to proceed</label>
            </td>
          <td width="64%" valign="top" class="field_data"><strong>Details:</strong>
          <textarea id = "Details1" class="where" name="Details1" cols="25" rows="2"></textarea></td>
          </tr>
     <tr>
          <td valign="top" class="field_name_left">Question 2</td>
<td valign="top" class="field_data">
   <label for="Yes">
            <input type="radio" name="Question2" value="Yes" validate = "required:true" /> Yes
            </label>
            <label for="No">
   <input type="radio" name="Question2" value="No" /> No
            </label>
            <label for="Question2" class="error">You must answer this question to proceed</label>
        </td>
     <td valign="top" class="field_data"><strong>Details:</strong>
              <textarea id = "Details2" class="where" name="Details2" cols="25" rows="2"></textarea>           </td>
   </tr>
          <tr class="submit_btn">
                          <td colspan="3">
                                <input type="submit" name="-edit" value="Finish">
                                <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset">            </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
      </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

On your `<textarea>` elements, add a [dependency expression](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/required#dependency-expression) for [`required`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/required), for example for question 1, do this:

```
validate="required:'input[name=Question1][value=Yes]:checked'"
```

This says if `$('input[name=Question1][value=Yes]:checked').length > 0` then the field is required, so if Yes is checked, it's required  :)

[You can see a working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/H2YLp/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've added the code into the <textarea> elements but when I select Yes it still lets me submit the form without entering any text into the Details field. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Steve - Here's your code with what I have above added and working, make sure the quotes and all are correct: http://jsfiddle.net/H2YLp/

Comment: OK thanks that's great I've got it working now. I appreciate your help, didn't realise it would be quite a simple change to implement this.

This is really a bonus question but I would also like to make the label for the textarea input field change colour to red once the user clicks Yes to indicate that this is now a required field. Clicking No would remain black. So if the user clicks Yes for Question 1 the: <strong>Details:</strong> for Question 1 would then change colour to red. Any ideas?

Comment: @Steve - That would be a `.change()` handler on those elements, here's an example, note how I change the labels...this should be how your `<label>` elements relate to your `<input>` elements :) http://jsfiddle.net/8J3K6/

Comment: Thanks Nick - that changes the label for "Yes" in the radio button input. What I want to do is change the label for "Details" if the corresponding answer is "Yes". So user clicks "Yes" to Question 1 and the Details label changes to red.

Also selecting "Yes" for an answer and trying to Submit displays the error under the Details textarea as expected. However if you change your answer to "No" it doesn't remove the error label under the textarea field - do you know if there is a way to remove it when "No" is clicked if it was displayed?

Comment: cool solution - i like how you don't have to pollute the class attribute using $.metadata

Answer (score 15):

You can do something like this:

```
$("#editRecord").validate({
    rules: {
        'Details1': {
            required: function() {
                return $('input[name=Question1]').val() == 'yes';
            }
        }
        'Details2': {
            required: function() {
                return $('input[name=Question2]').val() == 'yes';
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Javascript is case sensitive, especially on strings ;)

Comment: OK thanks that's great I've got it working now. This is really a bonus question but I would also like to make the label for the textarea input field change colour to red once the user clicks Yes to indicate that this is now a required field. Clicking No would remain black.

So if the user clicks Yes for Question 1 the:

    <strong>Details:</strong>

for Question 1 would then change colour to red. Any ideas?

Comment: You could just do that using $(element).on('change' function () { //change border here });

Also thanks to this answer - found it to be a simpler implementation then the accepted answer, for my problem which was slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

In response to Nick Craver's suggested response above, I found the correct syntax to be:

class="validate[required][name=Question1][value=Yes]:checked"

instead of what he posted.

Thanks for putting me on the right track, though!