# jQuery validate textarea on dropdown selection

Tags: jquery, validation, drop-down-menu, textarea

I have a form that has a dropdown list. When the Other option is selected in the dropdown i show some textarea fields. I would like to validate those fields when the Other option is selected in my dropdown. If any other option in my dropdown is select i don't want to validate thoses textarea fields is there hidden anyway.

Here is my jquery (that is not working) :

```
$("#form_182748").validate()({
element_19: "required",
element_99: {
required: function(element) {
return $("select#element_99").val() == 'Autre';
}
}
});
```

element_19 is my textarea that as to be validated if option Other is selected from element_99 (dropdown list). The validation has to happen when the user clicks on submit.

Comment: I already tried something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862126/conditional-validation-using-jquery-validation-plugin

Comment: But it doesn't work. Do i have to add class="required" to every dropdown and textarea? I must do the validation on the submit of the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```
$("#YourDropDownId").change(function()
{
   if($("#YourDropDownId").val() == "Other Option")
   {
       // Validate
   }  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in your validation you can test if the element is visible like this:

```
if ($(element).is(":visible")) {
   //DO VALIDATION
}
```