# jquery validator with rules defined in php

Tags: php, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validator plugin

http://jqueryvalidation.org

my qsn is relevant to this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2862194/932473,

mainly I need to give a function, based on some rules to be required or not required. The difference is that I need and I have the rules as an array in my php, like

```
$validationMessages['rules'] = array(
    'email' => array(
        'required' => 'function () { return $("#myDiv").length; }',
    )
);
```

then I have in js

```
var rules = $.parseJSON('<?php echo json_encode($validationMessages['rules'])?>');
```

Now, when I submit the form it says

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: function () { return $("#myDiv").length; }
```

when instead of a function in php I set set `required => true` it works fine, but with function definition gives that error ? How I can define the function in php and make it work in js ?

Thanks

Comment: @LorenzMeyer, I think u misunderstood, perhaps it is my fault, the function is not a php function, it is a js function, I updated the qsn, pls lemme know if it makes sense

Comment: name your function `'required' => 'function myFunction() { return $("#myDiv").length; }',`

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry.

Comment: Did my suggestion fix your problem?

Comment: still the same `unrecognized expression: function myFunction() { return true; }`

Comment: sry for late reply, was giving it a try

Comment: You can not assign a function to a var in this manner. Why is this within a function? couldn't you just use `'required' => '$("#myDiv").length;'`

Comment: no does not work, even if myDiv exists it does not consider as true

Comment: What you're trying to do seems unclear.  Just forget about the PHP for a moment and try to get the JavaScript working first.

Comment: @Sparky, in js everything is fine, there is no prob, I just wanna pass the rules from php, and passing a function does not work. `function myFunction() { return true; }` is just a simple example that it does not work, if I get it working I will handle the rest. tks

Comment: Well, then if the JavaScript is working fine, this is not a jQuery or jQuery Validate problem at all.  It's just a problem with your PHP someplace.  Look at the _rendered_ page source... how is it different from your working version?

Comment: with php everything is fine as well, I think the problem is this http://solutoire.com/2008/06/12/sending-javascript-functions-over-json/, have not tried yet for my case, but looks like the same problem with json_encode and js functions. tks

Answer (score 0):

You need to save your json to string variable and use this variable as parameter in $.parseJSON. Like this:

```
var rulesJson = '<?php echo json_encode($validationMessages["rules"])?>';
var rulesObj = $.parseJSON(rulesJson);
```

Comment: tks but does not work, gives another error in jquery min `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ',' or '}' after property value in object`

Comment: var valid = '{"email":{"required":"function () { return $('#myDiv').length; }"}}'; Tak a look at this string. Either way it's invalid JSON or String, you would need to find a way to get string with escaped characters from PHP.

Comment: yeah, found that out a few hours ago, here is an article, have not tried, but looks like the same issue http://solutoire.com/2008/06/12/sending-javascript-functions-over-json/ tks

Comment: Yes it is. If there is some fixed ammount of possible functions i'd just declare them in html and add them to json object, maybe based on some id from php. Also you can modify these functions by sending some content from php.